# http.post Sends the 3rd variable empty

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

The code gets the username and password from the user's inputs. Then it gets the device Mac Address using the 2 functions. I know this part can be simplified, I'm open to recommendations.

I'm 100% sure that $scope.data.macAddr is not empty because I'm able to print it on the console. I was worried about the data type, but I confirmed it that is a string using the "type" of, which returns 'String'.

Update: Also when I inspect the post headers only username and password are sending over.

I don't understand why http.post sends an empty/ not passing it at all to the server.

P.S I know about the MD5 risks. I'm using MD5 just to test my code. Eventually, at the end, I will use HTTPS/SSL with Bcrypt

```
var link = 'http://app.example.com/api.php';

      MacAddress.getMacAddress(function(macAddress){$scope.getMacAddr(macAddress);}, function(fail){console.log(fail);});

      $scope.getMacAddr = function(macAddr) {
        $scope.macAddr = macAddr;
        $scope.data.macAddr = macAddr;
      }

      $http.post(link, {
        username: md5.createHash($scope.data.username),
        password: md5.createHash($scope.data.password),
        macAddr: $scope.data.macAddr
       }).then(function(res) {

        console.log(typeof ($scope.data.macAddr));
```

[image: Request Headers]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so you have two asynchronous calls here. One is the call to get the MAC address, and one is the http post. Here is what happens:

1. At T0: You call getMacAddress(), passing a callback function that will be called, later, when the mac address is available
2. At T1: You send an HTTP request, passing a callback to then()
3. At T1000: The mac address is available: the callback passed at step 1 is called, and initializes `$scope.data.macAddr`
4. At T150000: the http response is available. The callpack passed at step 2 is called, and prints `$scope.data.macAddr`.

Send your http request from inside the callback function that you pass at step 1, when the mac address is available.

Comment: Makes sense. I just moved the getMacAddress a bit higher, so it will get its time to be called and return the requested data. So later on I'll use them on the http.post. Thanks JB!